# 64-bit kernel module crashing when called by 32-bit client

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, compatibility

I've written a 64-bit kernel module that works fine for 64-bit apps, but crashes for 32-bit apps. I need to figure out how how to make the module detect if a client is a 32-bit app, and, if so manage the conversion between the 32-bit struct and 64-bit struct in my module so the system calls work.

When the module is used by a 32-bit app, the `recvmsg()` function crashes if the msg has cmsghdrs, because the `cmsghdr` struct has different size in a 32-bit app.

My module doesn't provide a 32-bit compatibility layer explicitly, even though the kernel is configured to support 32-bit applications in compatibility mode.

The module implements a new protocol, defines `struct proto_ops`, but I don't see `compat_recv` in the proto ops.

The module acts as a proxy between the client and another application (64-bit), wherein it fetches responses to client requests from the backend using `netlink` messages as opposed to making `__sys_socket*()` calls.

Comment: Please have a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)! As it is right now it is an absolute horror to read!

Comment: I edited your very unclear hard to read post and confusing question title to make it much easier to read and quicker to understand. You should put some effort into learning to ask clearer questions because yours was put on a review queue to see if anyone wanted to help fix the question which was called a "low quality post".

Comment: Please review my changes and *edit* your answer and fix any mistakes I may have made and make sure the question is correct. And notice that after I thought about your question and each part of what you were saying I was able to introduce the actual basic problem at the top, and reduce the size, wording, formatting and make it much quicker to read and much clearer to understand.

Comment: sorry about poor formatting. will make a note of this and will improve in my next post. thanks for formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compat_recv is not needed in proto_ops. 32 bit userspace call to recvmsg in 64 bit kernel should go through compat_sys_recvmsg, which set MSG_CMSG_COMPAT flag. That flag makes ___sys_recvmsg() do necessary conversions before doing callback to your proto_ops and before returning to userspace.

References (in kernel tree):

- Compatibility System Calls (Generic) chapter of: /Documentation/adding-syscalls.txt
- /net/compat.c
- /net/socket.c

Regards,
Mateusz.

Comment: I bet you got that answer because it was much easier to understand your question when it was carefully and thoughtfully constructed and formatted well. Not to belabor the point - just to help you get the sense that it real does make a difference and helps you get the answers you need. That was a pretty quick answer and looks like a good-quality answer.